# pass/send multiple values to a jQuery function with var name & element [init(div:'#div',txt:'hello') / init(div='#div',txt='hello')]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I want to know that how can I pass/send value to a jQuery function with variable name and element?

like:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      init(div:'#div',txt:'hello'); //init(div='#div',txt='hello');
  });


  function init(div,txt){
    ....
  }
```

I can directly pass/send the values to this function via `init('#div','hello');`, but the major problem with this process is that i have to define these values in same manner (as defined in the function `[div - 1st, txt - 2nd]`).

how can i send these same values with there appropriate variable name. so that if i can define these values where i want, like `init(txt:'hello')` / `init(div:'#div')` / `init(txt:'hello',div:'#div')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      init( { div:'#div', txt:'hello' } );
  });


  function init( obj ){
     obj.div; //  '#div'
     obj.txt; //  'hello'
  }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/XPD4T/

Comment: perfect answer @cherniv :)

Comment: hi, please take a look of this "http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/29381565?noredirect=1". Thanks